# How to rotate object around self center without any misshape?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After adding instantiated prefab to parent I want to rotate that new prefab around self Center.

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate(mockup, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;

clone.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
clone.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
clone.transform.Rotate (0, 45, 0);
```

But it misshape prefab. In case when I not set parent it rotates without misshaping. I tried also RotateAround and pass `clone.transform.localePosition` as parameter but still the same.
I tried also to get center as

```
clone.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
```

and add to position and that pass as parameter but still no success.

How to rotate object around self center without any misshape ?

Misshape: camera is above and I scale and rotate cube but from above it is not rectangle as it should be

[image]

without rotation:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by misshape?

Comment: @Programmer I added image to question to clarify

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. It is rotating the Object you instantiated in local space.  Can you show image before rotation and image after rotation. Please take this image from top view with camera face down instead of side view. Maybe that can help determine what's going on

Comment: @Programmer I added image, when comment this lineclone.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; and rotate it looks good ( I could'n put third image, do not have enough points )

Comment: Is the first image you have top view? It doesn't look like a top view. If not please update the first first picture with image of top view after rotating. Also you said **when I not set parent it rotates without misshaping**. How do you set the parent? You code does not show you are making it a child of another GameObject? Are you trying to rotate a prefab that is child of another GameObject?

Comment: @Programmer Both images are top view, you can see by unity's line intersection gray color. I set to be parent with line clone.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; ( I see difference in hierarchy in Unity when I run with commented and uncommented line ). I am trying to rotate object which is child of another object around child center position. Imagine that I have table and I have one prefab cube and I want to make X ( tic tac sign, two prefabs are crossing ) I need to rotate my prefab for 45 degrees  around self center

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. I also missed that part you make it child. I see it now. One more thing question. When you say self center, you mean you want to center the child object to the child object instead of centering it to the parent object? Where was the child object made? In Unity or other 3D software? I just want to make sure that the pivot point is ok.

Comment: @Programmer I have attached c# script to parent object ( in this case plane ) and I instantiate prefab ( simple cube made prefab ) in Start method. I am not sure how Rotation can reshape object ( it is not skew, it is just rotation ). My default prefab is horizontal and I need by 45 degree rotated on that position.

Comment: I would recommend that you recheck your prefab and plane, and even camera. I just created a test setup and ran your code and it works perfectly. To create the prefab you show in the second picture, how did you do that? maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: @Mooda I found your problem. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After experiment I was able to replicate your probem. Your problem is on this line of code `GameObject clone = Instantiate(mockup, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;`

You are passing `transform.rotation` as the new position of the new `Instantiated` GameOBject. `transform.rotation` is the rotation of the GameObject your script is attached to. The **X** or the **Z** axis of that GameObject your script is attached to is are **0**. Mine was 25 and yours should be something similar.

**Several ways to fix it**:

**1**.Simply make sure that **X**,**Y** or **Z** axis of the GameObject the script is attached to are set to **0**. If you don't want to change this then do one of the other solutions below.

[image]

**2**.Another way of solving this is by **not** proving the position or rotation during `Instantiate` since you will override both the position and rotation with `clone.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;` and `clone.transform.Rotate (0, 45, 0);` later on. So, your current code is redundant.

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate(mockup) as GameObject;
```

**3**.Finally, another way to solve this is to provide **0** rotation `Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero)` to the third parameter instead of `transform.rotation`.

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate(mockup, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero)) as GameObject;
```